# Find AB and BA in a string without overlapping

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, find

Find AB and BA in a string without overlapping.
The order of AB and BA is not important.
I'm having trouble writing this app as follows:

```
s = input()
chars = set('AB' and 'BA')
if all((c in chars) for c in s):
    print('YES')
```

For example, if the input is ABBA, the answer is YES. If there is a `BAAB` input, then I have YES. But if the input is `ABA`, the answer is NO, or if the input is `ABHA`, then the answer is NO.

```
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: Maybe try searching the 'remainder' of the string, so once you find 'AB' in 'ABBA RULES', search 'BA RULES' to see if 'BA' is contained within it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem for regular expressions:

```
import re
s = input()
if re.search("(AB.*BA|BA.*AB)", s):
    print("Yes")
```

[*Demo*](https://regex101.com/r/rI1OB1/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without using regex:

```
word = input()
ab_pos = word.find('AB')
ba_pos = word.find('BA')
if ab_pos != -1 and ba_pos != -1:
    if word.find('BA', ab_pos + 2) != -1:
        print("YES")
    elif word.find('AB', ba_pos + 2) != -1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print("NO")
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you write a short description, how your solution works.